# ScalaTest errors on assert and test in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I am fairly new to Scala and Intellij and brand new to ScalaTest. I have set up Intellij 14 and `Scala 2.11.4` with the latest Scala plugin and everything works fine. I then tried to introduce ScalaTest and I am very confused. I downloaded the latest version of ScalaTest (`scalatest_2.11-2.2.1.jar`) from `scalatest.org`.  I went into my project structure and selected "Modules", clicked the green plus sign and added `scalatest_2.11-2.2.1.jar`.  All went well and I can see the scalatest jar in `External Libraries` in my project. When I created my first test it imported `org.scalatest.Funsuite` and the class extended FunSuite and all was well. I then tried a very simple test that I copied from the Internet.

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class MyTest extends FunSuite {
    test("this is a test") {
        assert(true)
  }
}
```

I get 2 errors. It can not resolve the "assert" reference with that signature and for the "test" method it says `unspecified value parameters Seq[Tag]: () => BoxedUnit`.

I can see other method signatures for "assert" and "test" but I can not use the most basic ones.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I didn't get exactly the same error messages, I had similar overall problems until I realized that you need two more JARs to use ScalaTest successfully: `scala-reflect-2.11.4.jar` and `scala-xml-2.11-1.0.2.jar`.

If you insist on doing this by hand you should also make sure that you have your tests in a directory that is marked as a "tests" directory -- so is highlighted in green: you can achieve this on the same "Modules" tab, but in the "Sources" sub-tab rather than "Dependencies". You also need to check that in the "Scope" column of the "Dependencies" sub-tab, the jars you added are marked as "Test" rather than "Compile".

If, on the other hand, you create an SBT project in IntelliJ rather than a regular Scala project, you could just add the following to your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test"
```

Re-import the build.sbt when prompted, then you can start writing and running tests: all the dependencies and test directories are set up correctly and it all "just works". I just created an empty project this way and ran your example. It took about a minute from beginning to end.

Obviously you're facing a trade-off between managing JARs by hand and learning yet another tool, but at this point learning the very basics of SBT may be worth your while.

Comment: I do have both scala-reflect.jar and the scala-xml_2.11-1.o.2 jars included in my scala-sdk-2.11.4   
I already had the tests directory set up as you described.
I tried changing the scope from "Compile" to "Test" but that unfortunately did not change anything.
I still have the same errors.

Comment: I put back things the way they were and, even though I still had the 2 errors, I went ahead and ran  the test and it works just fine. If I assert(true) the test passes and if I assert(false) the test fails. So why would IntelliJ be reporting the errors in the editor even though it runs OK?

Comment: Sometimes in such cases it helps to use File/"Invalidate Caches / Restart" and click "Invalidate and Restart". I've had such problems a lot in Idea 14 with Scala. It can also help to check through your other Scala settings in File/Settings: under "Languages and Frameworks"/"Scala" and /"Scala Compile Server", and also "Build, Execution, Deployment"/"Compiler"/"Scala Compiler". Basically just look for dramatic inconsistencies.

Comment: "Invalidate Caches/Restart"... IT WORKED. Thank you so much!